# How not to use the position for searching in SQL?

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a problem with my code because ListView stores items like this:

```
Item 1 - position 0
Item 2-position 1
...
```

The problem is that when I delete an item I am using his position to search for the ID in the database. Example:

```
Item 1 - position 0 ->search for data which have ID 1 (is position + 1)
Item 2 - position 1 ->search for data which have ID 2 (is position + 1)
and so on...
```

First time it works. But after I delete an item it will be like this:

```
Item 1 - position 0 ->search for data which have ID 1
Item 2 - deleted
Item 3 - position 1 ->search for data which have ID 2 --> the problem is that it should look for ID = 3, but the position is confusing.
```

Ideas? I was thinking of getting the ID from database when I press the item, but I don't know how to do it.
The final result should look like that:

```
Item 1 - ID 1 - search data with ID1
Item 2 - deleted
Item 3 - ID 3 - search for data with ID3
```

CODE:

```
colegiListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColegDataEditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Id", Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(id)));
        Log.i("Position",position+"");
        //save the id problem - maybe position
        Log.i("Id",position+"");
        startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this).toBundle());
    }
});
```

CODE from the new activity:

```
//getting Data from previous activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
id = intent.getIntExtra("Id", 0) + 1;

//showing it to EditTexts
Cursor data = mDatabase.getSpecificData(id);
```

CODE from getSpecificData:

```
public Cursor getSpecificData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this. getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TableName + " WHERE ID ="+id, null);
    return data;
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY - ALL CODE:

```
package com.example.schoolbox;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView addColegButton, deleteAllColegiButton, helloTextView;
    ListView colegiListView;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabase = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ArrayList<coleg> ColegiList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String last_name, first_name, email, label;
        int number;

        helloTextView = findViewById(R.id.bunaTextView);
        addColegButton = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        deleteAllColegiButton = findViewById(R.id.textViewMinus);
        colegiListView=findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        deleteAllColegiButton = findViewById(R.id.textViewMinus);

        //Set the helloTextView value
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if (hour >= 12 && hour <= 18) {
            helloTextView.setText(R.string.bună);
            helloTextView.setTextSize(43);
        }
        if (hour >= 18 && hour <= 24) {
            helloTextView.setText(R.string.bunăSeara);
            helloTextView.setTextSize(39);
        }
        if (hour >= 0 && hour <= 12) {
            helloTextView.setText(R.string.bunăDimi);
            helloTextView.setTextSize(36);
        }

        //fill the ColegiListView
        Cursor data = mDatabase.getData();
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            coleg coleg = new coleg(data.getString(1),data.getString(2),data.getString(3),Integer.parseInt(data.getString(4)));
            ColegiList.add(coleg);
        }

        //Declare ColegiList and set adapter
        ColegListAdapter adapter = new ColegListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, ColegiList);
        colegiListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Set the OnItemClick
        colegiListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColegDataEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Id", Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(id)));
                startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this).toBundle());
            }
        });

        //plusButton
        addColegButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColegInfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this).toBundle());
            }
        });

        //Declare DeleteAllButton
        deleteAllColegiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteClassmates);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positiveDialogButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mDatabase.deleteData();
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negativeDialogButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

                builder.create().show();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Rather than basing how you retrieve IDs from their position, that's data you should pass along. Removed records in a database typically result in autoinc key gaps, but that's not a problem if you don't make your program dependant on predictable identifiers

Answer (score 0):

You could get a list of the items that you want to display from the database first and then populate the ListView with the data of the items.

(The example code below may not fit your implementation completely but should give an idea about how it could work.)

The list of items could look something like this (you should change it to get the data from the database, you only need to get the ids if you do not want to display other data):

```
final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(new Item(1, "Item 1"));
items.add(new Item(3, "Item 3"));
items.add(new Item(4, "Item 4"));
```

You can then display the items on the list by setting an adapter like this (you should change the layout/textview for your needs):

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.textView, items);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

When the user clicks an item, you can get the item from the list with the position. Then you can read the id of the item and use that when getting the specific data of the item.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Item item = items.get(position);
        int itemId = item.getId();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on id " + itemId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

As items are added in another activity, you could start the add item activity for a result. You can then execute code in the main activity when the user returns from the activity where they added an item.

When the user returns from the add item activity, you could reload the list of items by executing the SELECT query again and updating the ListView with the new data.

Look here for more information about starting an activity for a result:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but the problem is in the first piece of code that you wrote. Items are created with details from another activity and I don't know how many items I will have. I was thinking at an increment function. Could you edit your answer based on that, please? If you need more code context just ask. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer with a possible solution to show newly added items in another activity.

Comment: Hi! I read something about the recyclerview. Do you think that would help me in some way?

Comment: Not necessarily. That seems to be directed for large or frequently changing datasets. If your dataset fits into one of those descriptions, then you should consider using it. You could try it anyway, maybe you will learn something that helps you later.